# AG Grid v27 - suppressRowVirtualization loads every page instantly

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I have a grid that uses serverSide pagination & **serverSideStoreType="partial"** since I updated ag-grid to v27 from v24.

I want to use **suppressRowVirtualisation="true"** because scrolling reduces performance heavily, however, setting that option to true seems to load data for all my pages without waiting for the user to scroll at the bottom of the declared cacheBlockSize.

Is there a way to make **suppressRowVirtualisation** work alongside serverSide pagination?

All help is appreciated!

```
<ag-grid-angular #stopPointsGrid style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="ag-theme-material" [modules]="modules"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" suppressCellFocus="true" suppressHorizontalScroll="true" rowSelection="multiple"
    [rowModelType]="rowModelType" [cacheBlockSize]="cacheBlockSize" suppressRowClickSelection="true"
    serverSideStoreType="partial" suppressColumnVirtualisation="true" suppressRowVirtualisation="true"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" (rowClicked)="rowClicked($event)" [isFullWidthRow]="gridsService.isFullWidthRow"
    [fullWidthCellRenderer]="gridsService.fullWidthCellRenderer" [suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns]="true">
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like `suppressRowVirtualisation=true` works as expected.

If you look at the docs at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/dom-virtualisation/#suppress-virtualisation

> Note if suppressRowVirtualisation=true, then there is no Row Buffer and the rowBuffer property is ignored.

Which means if you turn off row virtualisation your entire table will be rendered in the DOM.

What do you mean by scrolling reduces performance? I build big grids and scrolling and loading async works perfectly fine. You maybe can look at:

- adjust your buffer size when new entries are loaded
- improve your api if requests are too slow
- if you use custom cell renderer improve their performance and understand how `refresh` works

Comment: Without suppressRowVirtualisation, scrolling reduces performance heavily because it keeps rendering & removing elements from the dom. I've tested it with dev tools and the fps have massive drops when going up and down the grid.

Comment: Also, using rowVirtualization along with a rowBuffer that is the size of cacheBlockSize (in my case 50) has the same effect.

Comment: adding and removing elements to the DOM is way more performant than rendering 1000 rows upfront ;D like I said if you use custom components you need to improve their performance. would help if you create a plunkr or stackblitz to reproduce